# Having trouble with python equivalent of lambda attribute in ElasticNetCV

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, glmnet

I am trying to convert `r` code to `Python`.

The below is the code to find min lambda. It is glmnet cross validation.

```
model_cvfit = cv.glmnet(x, y)

model_cvfit $lambda.min
```

How could this be done using `ElasticNetCV` in python? I tried reading the documentation from `sklearn`. It didn't help

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [notes](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNetCV.html):

> The parameter l1_ratio corresponds to alpha in the glmnet R package
>   while alpha corresponds to the lambda parameter in glmnet.

So you can get alpha chosen by the cv by accessing `alpha_` property:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNetCV
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

X, y = make_regression(n_features=2, random_state=0)
regr = ElasticNetCV(cv=5, random_state=0)
regr.fit(X, y)  

>>> (regr.alpha_, regr.alphas_.min()) 
(0.1994727942696716, 0.1994727942696716)
```